# Quartz2d gradient fill an oval

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I have a simple drawing routine that allows the user to draw two enclosed ovals on the screen. I want to fill the ovals with a gradient, using the inner oval to represent the "percentage" of the gradient.  i.e. Th gradient will smoothly transition between the outside oval to the inside oval.

I have the interactive drawing working fine, now I just need to fill with the gradient.

Any thoughts? The docs only talk about perfectly circular gradients, not ovals.

[image]

_mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know whether it is possible oval gradient . But you can transform circle to oval. The idea is to draw a circle in transformed coordinate system.

Sample of code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSaveGState(context);
   CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, 0.5);
   CGGradientRef gradient;
   CGColorSpaceRef colorspace;
   CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0};
   NSArray *colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
   colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorspace, (CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
   CGPoint startPoint, endPoint;
   CGFloat startRadius, endRadius;
   startPoint.x = 180;
   startPoint.y = 180;
   endPoint.x = 180;
   endPoint.y = 180;
   startRadius = 0;
   endRadius = 100;
   CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, startPoint, startRadius, endPoint, endRadius, 0);
   CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Result of running code:

[image: Result of running code:]